# Find the area and the angles formed by the diagonals of the rhombus given its height and the relationship between the height and the side length

Tags: geometry

**Find the area and the angles formed by the diagonals of the rhombus, if its height is two times smaller than the length of its side and is $4.2$.**

---

*My attempt*

Let's write down the height:
$$h=\frac{a}{2}=4.2=\frac{21}{5}$$
From that we have
$$\frac{a}{2}=\frac{21}{5}\leftrightarrow5a=42\leftrightarrow a=\frac{42}{5}=8.4$$
Therefore, the area is
$$A=\frac{21}{5}\cdot\frac{42}{5}=\frac{882}{25}=35.28$$
I'm quite sure that I've got the area right. I need help with finding the angles. So... can someone help me find them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hint: Area= Ht*width/2 ; diagonals cut orthogonally!

Comment: Oh yeah... it's the trick question then!